# How to pass extra parameter to event handling callback?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a button on which I want to attach an event listener. I also need to pass a extra parameter url to this function. I read about `apply` and I'm doing the following:

```
$('#list-button').on('click',postListing.apply([url]));
```

My problem is that as soon as this script is loaded `postListing` is called. I am not calling the function anywhere else. I need it to be called only on click.

Comment: Better to use anonymous function in such cases. `'click', function(event) { myAwesomeFn(event, dog, cat, kill); });`

Comment: Check `.bind` function. Also first argument of apply or call is context. You can try `postListing.bind(this, url)`

Comment: You can use a bind function like this `$('#list-button').on('click',postListing.bind(this, url);`

Comment: Yes. Note that variable that you bind will not have updated value and will hold same value. You should rather have code to fetch value inside handler

Comment: A possibly more intuitive way to do this is with custom JavaScript events. You create a custom event in jQuery, say, then add any properties you want, and then trigger that event when you receive the `click` (or whatever) event. Its listener will then do what you want and you can read its properties to get whatever you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between bind and call/apply is that bind doesn't call the function immediately much like it loads the data with the variable when needed

You can reformat your code so it looks like this

```
$('#list-button').on('click', postListing.bind(this, url));
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a way. It can be done using a closure:

```
var postListing = function(event, url){
        return function(){
               //Main functionality wrapped here
        };
};
```

And the event listener setting remains the same:

```
$('#list-button').on('click',postListing.apply([url]));
```